# Rewrite my simple Python code in a better mode

Tags: python, function, for-loop, lambda, tuples

I have a function

```
def max_f(tup, val):
    max = tup[0](val)
    out = tup[0]
    for funz in tup:
        new = funz(val)
        if new > max: 
            max = new
            out = funz
    return out
```

and I would like to write it in a better way. I tried with

```
def max_f2(tup, val):
    return (max(funz(val) for funz in tup))
```

but I should return a function, not a value. How could I?

These are some examples of correct outputs

```
tupleFunz=(lambda x: x + 3 ,lambda x: x * 2,lambda x: x % 2)
max_f(tupleFunz,4)(8) #=> 16
max_f(tupleFunz,1)(8) #=> 11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `max()` and the `key` argument with a lambda function:

```
def max_f(tup, val):
    return max(tup, key=lambda x: x(val))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> tupleFunz=(lambda x: x + 3 ,lambda x: x * 2,lambda x: x % 2)
>>> max_f(tupleFunz,4)(8)
16
>>> max_f(tupleFunz,1)(8)
11
```